# UIPanGestureRecognizer: where first touch happened?

Tags: ios, uipangesturerecognizer

Many tutorial store the coordinate of the first touch like this:

```
func panHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if sender.state == .began
    {
        originalCenter = self.center
    }
}
```

Is it any way to know exactly in which position touch happened, i.e. in the coordinate system of the superview?

Comment: Yes, we can get touches point through touches began protocols.

Comment: Like: `originalCenter = sender.location(in: self.superview)`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 let gestureView = sender.view
      let translation: CGPoint = sender.translation(in: gestureView)
 var   initialCenter = gesture.location(in: sender.view
              )
     if sender.state == .began {

            print("begin")


        }
 let point = CGPoint(x: CGFloat((initialCenter?.x)! + translation.x), y: CGFloat((initialCenter?.y)! + translation.y))
            print(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func panHandler(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        if sender.state == .began
        {
          print("locationOfBeganTap -> (.\(touch.locationInView(view).x - touch.translationInView(view).x), .\(touch.locationInView(view).y - touch.translationInView(view).y))")
        }
}
```